# TCP/IP Unity Android ERROR Helfe

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, tcp

Hey all I am making a android game using unity3d, I want to control my game from my laptop I made a TCP/IP chat like program to get the input from my keyboard to my android over internet I made one for my Laptop (Windows form APP) and one for Unity, everything works except for one little annoying error.

ERROR:
I want when I press the X button to move a sphere from point A to point B but when send the "x" value it says :

INTERNAL_get_position can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.

and when I close the Windows form APP the ball then moves what to do I tried the Awake and the start functions too.

PS: I am testing this on the same computer so its not about the IPAddresses.

here is my code for the unity part:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
public class CHAT : MonoBehaviour {
    private Socket sck;
    EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;

    //Gameobjects
   public Transform ball , point;
    //logic

   string xIsHere;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.9"), Convert.ToInt32("81"));
        sck.Bind(epLocal);
        epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.9"), Convert.ToInt32("80"));
        sck.Connect(epRemote);
        Debug.Log("COnnected");


    }

    void Awake()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
        sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCAllBack), buffer);

    }

    private void MessageCAllBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
    {
        try
        {
            int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(aResult, ref epRemote);

            if (size > 0)
            {
                byte[] receivedData = new byte[1464];
                receivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;

                ASCIIEncoding eEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string receivedMessage = eEncoding.GetString(receivedData);
               //bn3mal if statement bnshof weslat el X wela la2 w iza weslat bnmasi el tabeh
                xIsHere = receivedMessage;
                if (xIsHere.Contains("x"))
                {
                    Debug.Log("X is here");
                    ball.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(ball.position, point.position, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
                }

                //b3deen bntba3 el msg bs b7aletna bdna n5li el touch active.
                //ListMessage.Items.Add("Sender:" + receivedMessage);
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCAllBack), buffer);

        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            Debug.Log(exp.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem lies within the asychronous callbacks. `MessageCAllBack` will be called from another thread, and since Unity isn't thread-safe, any attempts to modify game objects will result in that error. Maybe you should try setting a flag after some content arives, and then update the position in your `Update()` function and clear the flag again? Maybe you could also use Coroutines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I fixed it I just changed the port I used 5050 and 5040 and it worked just fine, added an if statement n the update() function to make the object move.. anyways here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
public class CHAT : MonoBehaviour {
    private Socket sck;
    EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;

    //Gameobjects
   public Transform ball , point;
    //logic
  static Boolean conn = false,arrievedX = false;
   string xIsHere;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.8"), Convert.ToInt32("5050"));
        sck.Bind(epLocal);
        epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.9"), Convert.ToInt32("5040"));
        sck.Connect(epRemote);
        conn = true;
        Debug.Log("COnnected");



    }

    void Awake()
    {


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
        sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCAllBack), buffer);


        if (arrievedX)
        {

            ball.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(ball.position, point.position, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
        }

    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (arrievedX)
        {
            GUI.Box(new Rect(100, 100, 100, 25), "X is here");
        }
        if (conn)
        {
            GUI.Box(new Rect(100, 50, 100, 50), "Connected");
        }
        }

  private void MessageCAllBack(IAsyncResult aResult )
    {

        try
        {
            int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(aResult, ref epRemote);

            if (size > 0)
            {
                byte[] receivedData = new byte[1464];
                receivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;

                ASCIIEncoding eEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string receivedMessage = eEncoding.GetString(receivedData);
               //bn3mal if statement bnshof weslat el X wela la2 w iza weslat bnmasi el tabeh

                if (receivedMessage.Contains("x"))
                {
                    Debug.Log("X is here");

                    arrievedX = true;

                }

                //b3deen bntba3 el msg bs b7aletna bdna n5li el touch active.
                //ListMessage.Items.Add("Sender:" + receivedMessage);
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCAllBack), buffer);

        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            Debug.Log(exp.ToString());
        }

    }

}
```